# Make DMG Readonly

Tags: macos, dmg-image

There is information on how to do the opposite (which is hard to impossible), but how do I make a writeable DMG readonly?

The reason that I might want to do this -- because otherwise this question is too short and will not meet superuser quality standards -- is that I am distributing a DMG and I don't want it altered TOO easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
hdiutil convert /path/to/rwimage.dmg -format UDRO -o /path/to/readonlyimage.dmg
```

There are a number of other format options (with e.g. various kinds of compression); see the hdiutil man page for details.

Comment: What if I don't care about the type of compression? Or must I match the compression of the existing DMG? +1 and thanks

Comment: Apple seems to regard zlib compression (`-format UDZO`) as the "default", so I'd go with that.  There's no need to match the existing compression, especially since RW images aren't stored compressed.